# Serving notice by accepting an offer, got a call from another company, shall I disclose serving notice period already?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, hiring-process, recruitment, notice-period

I am serving my notice period as I accepted an offer from other company. Now I have received a call from another company which is bigger than the other for interview. They asked me why I was in notice. Is it bad to hide to hide that i already have an offer from other company? By saying I have, will that make me to loose that interview?

Comment: "They asked me why I was in notice." How did they know?

Comment: As Foo implies, you should never have told them you were in notice - never tell anyone anything.  **HOWEVER** if you are changing jobs, it's very advantageous to the new company to know you absolutely will be available on short notice.

Comment: You don’t just have an offer, which is normal. You have _accepted_ an offer. Once you have accepted an offer, that’s it. You are off the job market.

Comment: @gnasher729 and when do I get back? As soon as I join the new company?

Comment: You apply for jobs, get interviews, get offers, decide which offer is the best, accept the best offer and start with the company that made the best offer. Then you work there and they pay you. Did you accept too early? Don’t accept that early the next time.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let me say this:

You should not have disclosed that you're on notice period.

The only thing they can ask you or they need to know is: When (How soon) can you join? You can then, tell them the date you'll be okay to join. End of topic.

Now, coming to the point, when you have already disclosed you're on notice period,

> *Is it bad to hide to hide that i already have an offer from other company? By saying I have, will that make me to loose that interview?*

Yes, it is bad, and does not need hiding. There's nothing to hide about a standing offer. You don't need to disclose any details about the offers, but mentioning you already have offers does not hurt.

This will serve you good, because the new company will know that you already have a standing offer, and

- If by allowing you to interview there is a possibility of legal issues, then they will not go ahead.
- Otherwise, if they do not see any issue in going ahead and making an offer, they will know about the other offer and based on the requirement, your scope for negotiation is bettered.

That said, to mention whether you "should" accept a new offer, if you get one after the interview - this really depends. As mentioned in the comments,

- it may burn some bridges at the first company, if you chose to accept the new offer
- or you may feel demotivated after joining at the first offer, if you chose to refuse the new offer

both has it's ups and downs. It's your call at the end of the day, how you want to play.

Comment: Having accepted an offer and then changing your mind is completely different from going to multiple interviews at the same time.

Comment: @FooBar How is that "completely different"? The end target is same - to have a better offer.

Comment: The OP needs specific language to handle this situation.

Comment: It’s unprofessional, will severely burn bridges, I would never hire you, and in some countries it’s legal trouble. That’s completely different.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'll re-word my comment: If we're discussing about whether to accept a new offer after already accepting one - that would a different matter. The question is - whether we shall disclose about a standing offer or not. The answer to that is : yes, you can, there's nothing to hide.

Comment: I think this answer would be great for a different situation (someone who is interviewing and has offer(s) on the table but hasn't yet committed. But I think it's inappropriate for the OP's actual scenario. If you've already *accepted* an offer (i.e. entered into a contract with an employer) and then go interview somewhere else, prepare to be blacklisted by any recruiter or hiring manager that learns of this. No one likes people with such blatant disregard for commitment.

Comment: @dwizum Yes, to clarify my points, I've modified the answer. Did you read the updated one? You comment and my answer update collided.

Comment: I think it's a bit more nuanced than the comments are suggesting. There is nothing wrong/unprofessional about continuing to interview after accepting an offer. The only time wrong/unprofessional enters the equation is how you deal with a second, subsequent offer. If you just bail on the first company, _then_ that's unprofessional. Assuming you follow the proper process of giving notice (which is likely to be short if you're in probation) then that's fine. Keep it professional and follow what's in the contract you signed - if the company doesn't like it, well it's their contract.

Comment: I see your edit but I still don't really think you're directly addressing the OP's situation. The OP states that they have already accepted an offer. Your answer (and your comment above mine) both reference what to do when you have "a standing offer" which is a different situation.

Comment: @dwizum I understand that part, but whether OP accepted that offer or not, need not be disclosed IMHO. It's enough to mention having an offer, in what state - not really relevant. In case the company is interested in knowing more (legal reasons), they can ask.

Comment: Yes - you can absolutely hide that from the *new* employer, but the *old new* employer - the one you've accepted the offer from - is still, obviously, going to know that you accepted an offer and then rejected it. Which might not matter if you can dispose of potential employers without concern, but it may also mean that you are burning bridges that could lead to important opportunities in the future. This isn't just a theory, it actually happens, and regardless of what you tell the new employer it's important to consider the reputation impact.

Answer (score 1):

To frame-challenge your question a bit, it is important to emphasize this part of your question's text:

> I am serving my notice period as I accepted an offer from other company.

You're stating that you've already accepted an offer from another company. Generally, this is viewed as having entered into a contract with that employer. While, of course, no one is going to *force* you to work for that employer, there is still significance in the act of making that commitment. Recruiters and hiring managers generally expect employees and candidates to **respect their commitments.** Doing so is considered a good sign in terms of your value as an employee.

That said, **accepting an offer and then rejecting it because you got a better offer somewhere else is looked upon very poorly.** While it's true that your potential future employers may never know that you did this, at least *some* of them will likely know (including, obviously, the company you're potentially stepping away from now). The significance of this rejection cannot be understated in some circles - in my own community, in my line of work, it's pretty common practice for third party recruiters, internal recruiters, and hiring managers to literally **blacklist** people who walk away from accepted offers like this, and not consider them for future positions.

Of course, there are no hard and fast rules, and some recruiters or hiring managers may not care about this, especially if they're in a very difficult employment market, or one where turnover isn't particularly expensive (for instance, unskilled entry level staff that don't have a big recruiting or onboarding cost). The real question is, do you know which situation you're in? Is it a gamble you're willing to take?

If you want to work for this new employer so badly that you're willing to risk that, then go ahead and follow up with the interview opportunity. It sounds like they've already learned you're on a notice period, and they've asked for an explanation (which is what your question is actually asking about):

> They asked me why I was in notice. Is it bad to hide to hide that i already have an offer from other company?

If they haven't explicitly asked if you've accepted an offer elsewhere, and you haven't already disclosed that, it's probably not smart to specifically state that you've already accepted an offer (whether or not you're ethically comfortable with withholding that info is of course a question you have to ask yourself). Employers do expect that you'll be interviewing elsewhere and you may have other offers, so it's fair game to mention that generically, along the lines of stating that you *"have other opportunities."* That may even work in your favor, in the sense that it'll put the pressure on the new employer to act quickly if they want to make you a better offer.

As a final thought, there are plenty of questions on The Workplace asking about how to deal with very short tenures at employers, since "job hopping" is frowned upon. Consider that having accepted an offer, and then rejecting it to go for a *better* offer, is basically job hopping to the extreme - your tenure at the accepted offer was zero days!

Answer (score 0):

It's really none of their business.  You don't need to reveal if you have an offer already.    Nothing wrong with going to an interview and listening to them.

Bottom line is do what's best for you. If you would prefer to work at the other company, do it--you don't owe anyone.